# Authenticate requests from xamarin.forms to aws API Gateway with Cognito jwt token

Tags: amazon-web-services, xamarin.forms

I am trying to authenticate requests from xamarin.forms app to aws API Gateway.
Users are authenticated from a user pool and I am able to receive id/access/refresh tokens at the authentication.

I do not understand how to sign requests against the api gateway with the xamarin sdk.

**This functionality is supported by the sdk?**

Otherwise I could authenticate requests with aws signature v4. Even in this case I can't figure out how to use the tokens I receive from cognito to obtain the session token

from the docs (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-create-canonical-request.html):

> Note
>   You can use temporary security credentials provided by the AWS Security Token Service (AWS STS) to sign a request. The process is the same as using long-term credentials, but when you add signing information to the query string you must add an additional query parameter for the security token. The parameter name is X-Amz-Security-Token, and the parameter's value is the URI-encoded session token (the string you received from AWS STS when you obtained temporary security credentials).

**How can I build the v4 signature headers using Cognito tokens?**

Comment: Did you try using the SDK generation in API Gateway? You can pass the Cognito tokens to the SDK

Comment: Unfortunately there is no possibility to generate an sdk in c#